# Plotting non-numerical data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm a beginner in coding and I wrote some codes in python pandas that I didn't understand fully and need some clarification.

Lets say this is the data, `DeathYear`, `Age`, `Gender` and `Country` are all columns in an excel file.

[image: pl]

[How to plot a table with non-numeric values in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434495/how-to-plot-a-table-with-non-numeric-values-in-python)

I saw this question and I used this command

```
df.groupby('Gender')['Gender'].count().plot.pie(autopct='%.2f',figsize=(5,5))
```

it works and gives me a pie chart of the percentage of each gender,
but the normal pie chart command that I know for numerical data looks like this

```
df["Gender"].plot.pie(autopct="%.2f",figsize=(5,5))
```

My question is why did we add the `.count()`?
is it to transform non numerical data to numerical?
and why did why use the group by and type the column twice (`'Gender'`)`['Gender']`?

Comment: Yes, the .count() is transform Male and Female to a count of how many males and how many females. I suggest you try the groupby statement without the first ('Gender') or without the second ['Gender'] and see what happens. The first tells pandas to group the results by the gender category. The second says ONLY count the Genders.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address the second part of your question first since it makes more sense to explain it that way

1. The reason that you use `('Gender')['Gender']` is that it does two different things. The first `('Gender')` is the argument to the `groupby` function. It tells you that you want the DataFrame to be grouped by the 'Gender' column. Note that the `groupby` function needs to have a column or level to group by or else it will not work.
   The second `['Gender']` tells you to only look at the 'Gender' column in the resulting DataFrame. The easiest way to see what the second `['Gender']` does is to compare the output of `df.groupby('Gender').count()` and `df.groupby('Gender')['Gender'].count()` and see what happens.
2. One detail that I omitted in first part for clarity it that the output of `df.groupby('Gender')` is not a DataFrame, but actually a DataFrameGroupBy object. The details of what exactly this object is are not important to your question, but the key is that to get a DataFrame back you need to have a function that tells you what to put in the rows of the DataFrame that you wish to create. The `.count()` function is one of those options (along with many others such as `.mean()`, etc.). In your case, since you want the total counts to make a pie chart, the `.count()` function does exactly that; it will count the number of times 'Female' and 'Male' appears in the 'Gender' column and that sum will be the entries in the corresponding row. The DataFrame is then able to be used to create a pie chart. So you are correct in that the `.count()` function transforms the non-numeric 'Female' and 'Male' entries into a numeric value which corresponds to how often those entries appeared in the initial DataFrame.